# How do I set v8 options in node.js

Tags: node.js

For example, I want to disable the new heap snapshots so I type something like this:

`node --new_snapshot=false`

But I get an error: Error: illegal value for flag --new_snapshot=false of type bool

What am I missing about the syntax?

Comment: Perhaps you need to compile node with these options?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had to dig into v8 source code to get this. For some reason I couldn't find it documented. However, a boolean option is enabled by setting `--option` and disabled by using `--nooption` (note the `no` prefix).

So in your case use

```
node --nonew_snapshot
```

Comment: fantastic... I can't believe how much is undocumented though.

Comment: I also found out you have to restart node after putting no in front of the option.  In my case, I was using notrace_debug_json.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this while I was looking for something else and this is a better way to find out what is available in v8 on node.js. You can get the options by running the following command.

node --v8-options